# Downloading parquet files from Azure Blob Storage. File and folder with same names

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-blob-storage

I have created parquet files on Azure Blob Storage. And now I want to download them. Problem is it keeps failing. I think its because the is a file and folder with same names. Why is that? Do I just need the folder? Since the file is only 0B?

[image]

---

The error I get looks like:

[image]

Its saying that because it already downloaded the 0B file

Comment: What is the error message you’re getting?

Comment: The files and folders with the same name is there for a reason. WASB is not like the normal HDFS, it is a different implementation and that's why WASB automatically creates `Block Blob` of the folder name. Having said that, this is not the reason why you are facing issue. Can you share the error message?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman updated OP

Comment: @GauravMantri updated OP

Comment: One follow up question: are these folders empty or do they have some files in them? It could be an issue with the tool as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri the folders have files in them. Alternatively if I write a CSV, how do I download this? It seems like when I do a write ... I get many small files. Like part files

Comment: I think previously you might have downloaded the `Block Blob` file instead of the folder. Can you try removing them from your local machine and try again?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman so I can ignore all the `Block Blob` and just keep the rest?

Comment: Yep.. the `Block Blob` is Azure's implementation because it differs from our normal filesystem. For downloading/uploading, you don't have to download the `0 B` files. Just download/upload the folders.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman you can create an answer so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, instead of downloading the actual file, you might have downloaded the `Block Blob` file which is an Azure's implementation to handle and provide `FileSystem` like access when the blob storage is being used as a filesystem (Azure HDInsight clusters have their HDFS backed with Azure Blob Storage). Object storage like Azure Blob Storage and AWS S3 have these sort of custom implementation to provide (or simulate) a seamless filesystem like experience.

In short, don't download the `Block Blob`. Download the actual files.